# Getting ClassNotFoundException while running instrumentation on android app

Tags: android, unit-testing, instrumentation, android-instrumentation

I am getting **ClassNotFoundException** while testing my android app. Following is the details

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.TestActivity
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
```

My test class is as follows:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
class TestActivity {

@Rule
@JvmField
var homeActivity: ActivityTestRule<HomeActivity> = ActivityTestRule(HomeActivity::class.java, true, false)

@Before
fun setUp() {
    val intent = Intent()
    homeActivity.launchActivity(intent)
}

@Test
fun homeTest() {
    val activity = homeActivity.activity
    activity.openPage("syz", false)
}
}
```

Need help on this :)

Comment: How your app.gradle file looks like?

Comment: public class TestActivity make it public

Comment: @JeelVankhede in gradle, rules/runners all added.

Comment: @PrajwalW will try and check.

Comment: @PrajwalW It's kotlin, by default, public.

Comment: Pls show your project structure and manifest xml declaration of this class

Comment: @PrajwalW should this class be defined in manifest also ? if yes then can you please post the example code please ?

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.TestActivity - It says that the compiler cannot find the class TestActivity within the test package. Confirm if the test package has this class.